# Handling error handling and exception handling in GridDB effectively in a mission-critical application that uses GridDB as primary data storage

Tags: griddb

I'm building a mission-critical application that relies on GridDB as the primary data store. As part of ensuring system reliability, I want to establish robust error handling and exception handling practices in my GridDB code.

I would like to understand how to handle GridDB-specific exceptions, handle network failures, connection timeouts, and other error scenarios gracefully. Code examples showcasing error handling patterns, recommended logging frameworks and strategies, and any available GridDB error handling libraries or utilities would be highly valuable for developing robust error handling capabilities in my GridDB application.